# Interchange of limit operator and $\ln$ function.

Tags: improper-integrals

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right)$$

Can someone help evaluate that for me?

Comment: Where is the integral ?

Comment: Oh ye oops, no integral it just a limit (it is part of an improper integral which I already evaluated) - sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $\ln$ is a continuous function in $(0,+\infty)$ you can interchange the $\lim$ operator with $\ln$. Thus $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1/n^2+a^2}{1/n^2+1}\right)=\ln(a^2)$$

Comment: right but, when when take the limit as n tends to infinity, then won't you get, infinity / infinity? how do you know that that becomes a^2?

Comment: I would not say "ignore", just interchange. See my edit.

Comment: Oh ye that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As Stef said, $\ln$ is continuous, so you have :  $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right) = \ln \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right)\right)$$

Then :  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{a^2n^2}{n^2}\right) = a^2 $$

And finally : $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right) = \ln \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right)\right) = \ln(a^2)$$

This is valid if you suppose $a^2 \neq 0$. If $a = 0$, you have : $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1+a^2n^2}{1+n^2}\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+n^2}\right) = -\infty$$

Comment: Of course! +1. For no reason I assumed $a\neq0$ but one has to consider also the case $a=0$.